# use phtml code instead of xml code to display reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, product-view, phtml, review

i added below code in catalog.xml file , now reviews section is displaying in product view page. but i want to display that only under particular tab.

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/></block>
```

Is there any way we can use phtml code to display this review section.

so i am planning to use that phtml code under that tab

Comment: how to work tab is ajax or reload page for new tab.

Comment: @Naumov please check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , under `Review` tab i want to display the review section

Comment: You need just call method `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(''product_review') ?>` betwen `<div></div>` in you template tabs content. But block showld be insert in to block parent.

Comment: i added code between div tabs as here `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>` but still its not displaying for me, please check view.phtml file code here : http://pasted.co/40ee16fb

Comment: Check your layout.xml you need pust this block `<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/></block>` betwen `<reference name='blockname'></reference>` for example you block reviews add as `<block type="core/template" name="blockname" template="at.phtml"></block>` you need reference this block for get access to child block.

Comment: @Naumov thanks a lot , it worked for me by below answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
<?php
$reviewListBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/product_view_list');
$reviewFormBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/form');

echo $reviewListBlock->setTemplate('review/product/view/list.phtml')->toHtml();
echo $reviewFormBlock->setTemplate('review/form.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: sorry for delay, it didt worked for me.

Comment: i added your code in view.phtml file under particular tab section , but it didt displayed review section [there](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: I have checked this code in my project just before answering. Please recheck and let me know.

Comment: i added your code in several places in view.phtml file , but still not working for me. may be i am doing something wrong, can you please check view.phtml code : http://pasted.co/40ee16fb

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I forgot to add **echo** in last two lines. I hvae updated my answer.

Comment: its working fine now. if you click on `Add review` tab , you can see 2 parts , one is reviews that is already posted.
another section is `write your own review` i want to display `write your own review` section in another tab.

Comment: No problem, you can add a new tab and then call list.phtml and form.phtml in different tabs.
If possible, please post a different question or edit and add more description in your question.

Comment: i will add new question and inform you.

Comment: please check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124508/display-5-stars-for-adding-ratings-instead-of-radio-buttons)