# Display 5 stars for adding ratings instead of radio buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, tabs, ratings

default magento will display the ratings as below image

[image]

but i want to change like [this](http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition/write-review/ITMEGMRNZQJCPFG9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z&otracker=review_write_bottom) :

[image]

i am using default magento code

**form.phtml** [app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/form.phtml]

```
<?php if( $this->getRatings() && $this->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
                <h4><?php echo $this->__('Your Rating') ?> <em class="required"></em></h4>
                <span id="input-message-box"></span>
                <table class="data-table review-summary-table ratings" id="product-review-table">
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">1</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:20%;"><?php echo $this->__('1 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">2</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:40%;"><?php echo $this->__('2 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">3</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:60%;"><?php echo $this->__('3 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">4</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:80%;"><?php echo $this->__('4 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <span class="rating-number">5</span>
                                    <span class="rating nobr" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $this->__('5 star') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <td class="value"><label for="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /></label></td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-review-table')</script>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

**Edit**

i tried with this [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/277ke7g4/), it worked fine for me. but i want to know what code i need to be replace in form.phtml by jsfiddle code

Comment: try this https://github.com/srka/Srka-Magento-Review-Stars

Comment: Thanks @PradeepSanku i will try & let you know. even you can post this as an answer.

Comment: for couple of websites i had used this

Comment: @PradeepSanku is i need to add this code `<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var reviewStars = new SrkaReviewStars('product-review-table');
    //]]>
</script>` below `</form>` tag.

Comment: yes in template/review/form.phtml

Comment: @PradeepSanku but it didt worked for me. i added like this : http://pasted.co/f9c01d43

Comment: add the script just after </form>. not before </form> tag and check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to convert rating radio buttons to star rating

**Step 1:-**

Download `srka.review.stars.min.js` (or `srka.review.stars.js`) and `srka.review.stars.css` from https://github.com/srka/Srka-Magento-Review-Stars and upload to your theme css and js folders respectively.

**Step 2:-**

Add srka.review.stars.min.js (or srka.review.stars.js) and srka.review.stars.css files to the product page using local.xml file from yout theme's layout.

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/srka.review.stars.css</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/srka.review.stars.js</name></action>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

**Step 3:-**

Open app/design/frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/review/form.phtml and add the following code just below the #review-form closing tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var reviewStars = new SrkaReviewStars('product-review-table');
    //]]>
</script>
```

just save and clear cache and you have done.

Comment: sorry, it didt worked for me, can you check this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: i had checked your website in that js has not been included

Comment: make view source and check http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/srka.review.stars.js it is giving 404 error

Comment: please check link now, before i was uploaded directly under js folder present in root. js is loading now. but stars are not visible. radio buttons are hidden now.

Comment: under `add review tab` you can see this image : http://prntscr.com/bpttgz  instead of star, small square box is displaying.

Comment: i checked functionality and its working fine, only images are missing.

Comment: only  stars images are not displaying, from other [question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124618/ratings-stars-image-are-not-displaying/124621#124621) i heard its site issue.

Comment: when i check css code ,they mentioned this image path , but in extension there is no image . how to display stars, can you please guide me ?

Comment: you yourself can make this star images and place the images at respective path

Comment: Thansk a lot....

Comment: This works, but I'd like to maintain the hover effect on the siblings as you hover from left to right, and remove them as you move back from right to left. I've tried all kinds of different combinations of CSS, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @PradeepSanku Can we get image or sample image?

Answer (score 1):

at first time its not working for me but i found the solution, above given solution is working perfect with "base/default/template/review/form.phtml"

with other theme "form.phtml" it wont work. please try to replace code from base/default to your theme file.