# Ratings stars image are not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, image, review, ratings

For [this problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124508/display-5-stars-for-adding-ratings-instead-of-radio-buttons/124607?noredirect=1#comment168843_124607) We used this [github code](https://github.com/srka/Srka-Magento-Review-Stars) , now feature is working fine. but instead of stars, its displaying square boxes if we click inside textfield as here :

[image]

you can check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) after clicking `Add Review` Tab.

**git hub code**

```
SrkaReviewStars = Class.create();
SrkaReviewStars.prototype = {
    initialize: function(reviewTableId){
        var _this = this;
        _this.ratingTable = $(reviewTableId);
        _this.ratings = {};
        _this.html = '';

        this.ratingTable.hide();
        this.ratingTable.select('tbody > tr').each(function(row, row_count){
            var ratingCode = row.select('.radio')[0].readAttribute('name');
            var ratingLabel = row.select('th')[0].innerHTML;
            var ratingOptions = [];
            row.select('.radio').each(function(radio){
                ratingOptions.push(radio.value);
            });

            _this.ratings[ratingCode] = {
                code: ratingCode,
                label: ratingLabel,
                options: ratingOptions
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is only Image Missing Issue in site so your Image not display.

Your Code in almost Fine and Working Well just doing CSS for this image with Class.please check below screenshot for this.

[image]

Comment: okay i will try in another site, Thanks a lot.